# populate list with emmet

Tags: html, emmet

What is the Emmet syntax for

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried

```
(ul.menu>li*4>a[href="#"]{"one","two","three","four"})
```

with no avail.

Comment: funnily enough, it looks to be the exact example on the emmet homepage.  http://emmet.io/

Comment: only one i can come up with: ul.menu>li*4>a[href="#"]{$}

Comment: Use Wrap with abbreviation action instead: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the round brackets, that is:

```
ul.menu>li*4>a[href="#"]{"one","two","three","four"}
```

Note:Remember to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to autocomplete code when cursor is at the end of the emmet statement.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question, but just so you know - that is the correct syntax. You are supposed to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the code when your cursor is at the end of it.

Does that help?